# Is it possible to put minimized applications last in the task switcher?

Tags: unity, 16.10

The task switcher seems to base its order based on most recently used application, which is great unless I've just minimized an application. If I've minimized an application I'd like t to be placed last in the order. Is it possible to change the ordering of applications for when I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>?

[image: Task Switcher]